# Copy an Image and Text together to Clipboard, using ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Is there any way to copy an Image and some relevant text (Like a Description to the image, added programmatically), so that these can be pasted together (On some application like Excel; outside the Flex Application).

Comment: simple answer is no. many apps can automatically deal with one specific type of passed data but not that many can deal with 2 or more type of passed data at once. If you could from your desktop copy at once a pic and some text and then try to paste that in excel, how is excel gonna know what to do with all that?

Comment: Thanks Botmaster. I have resolved this issue by creating a hidden label and added the data to it, then loaded this to the Bitmap data.